# SELECT with INNER JOIN, GROUP BY by and WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a 3 MySQL tables about movies. First one is `movie`, second is `actor` and last one is `movie_actor_mapping`.

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` float(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `runtime` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plot` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) 


CREATE TABLE `actor` (
  `actor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_en` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `movie_actor_mapping` (
  `movie_actor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movie_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `movie_actor_id` (`movie_actor_id`)
)
```

Some movies has `NULL` in rating and when I do `SELECT` I have to select all movies which has rating and order them by rating. My `SELECT` looks like:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors
FROM movie m INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma
ON m.movie_id=ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a
ON a.actor_id=ta.actor_id
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Also I wrote a `select` and `order` `SELECT * FROM movie WHERE rating is not null ORDER BY rating DESC;` but I don't understand how to split these queries. I know that if I will not have `GROUP BY` - I can write my second query after `ON` but how to do that using `GROUP BY`?

**UPD:**

I add example data from my tables. So, for `movie` it's:

```
1 | "American Horror Story" | "2011–" | 8.2 | "60 min" | "Both physical..."
```

A data from `actor` table:

```
1 | Evan Rachel Wood
```

From `movie_actor_mapping`:

```
1 | 21 | 1
```

Comment: can you please give me some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hi @Faisal, I updated my post!

Comment: your sample data is not clear please try to add more details like more columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question, because it seems too simple, but this query:

```
SELECT m.*, group_concat(a.name separator ', ') as actors
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma ON m.movie_id = ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = ma.actor_id
WHERE m.rating IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY m.movie_id
ORDER BY m.rating DESC
```

...is selecting movies with rating, groups actors and orders them by rating

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! Maybe for you my question too simple, but for me it's not :). Your query does what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *, group_concat(a.name order by rating desc separator ', ' ) as actors
FROM movie m INNER JOIN movie_actor_mapping ma
ON m.movie_id=ma.movie_id
INNER JOIN actor a
ON a.actor_id=ta.actor_id
WHERE rating is not null
GROUP BY m.movie_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `GROUP BY`, you need to have some aggregation action on those returned values that are not used for grouping (for instance, COUNT, MAX, MIN, etc.).

If what you want is to get the list of movies where all records of a specific movie are together, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause. In your case, it could be `movie_id`.